# How to make pydev show doc for built-in python functions?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Now for built-in functions, pydev just shows:

```
  list.append Found at: builtins
```

while for a function in matplotlib, it shows:

```
def figure Found at: matplotlib.pyplot

def figure(num= # autoincrement if None, else integer from 1-N
    None, figsize= # defaults to rc figure.figsize
    None, dpi= # defaults to rc figure.dpi
    None, facecolor= # defaults to rc figure.facecolor
    None, edgecolor= # defaults to rc figure.edgecolor
    None, frameon=True, 
    FigureClass=Figure, **
    kwargs):
.....................
```

I've installed python-docs package in my linux system, what can I do to make it show detailed function hints for built-in python functions?

Comment: Any other IDE/Editor solution suggestions with nice doc integration is also welcomed.